# Is the Lorentz force law really the full (classical) characterization of how particles react to the EM field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, dipole

Classically, the effect of the electromagnetic field on particles is often said to be given by the Lorentz force law:

$$ \vec{F} = q\vec{E} + q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}. $$

However, I'm really starting to doubt this is entirely the true equation. We know there are neutral particles such as the neutrino that have a nonzero dipole magnetic moment. If we take the above equation at face value (perhaps naively), then the fact that a neutron has $q=0$ must mean the neutron has $\vec{F} = 0$ force.

Something here is clearly wrong, because a non-uniform magnetic field imposes a [force on a particle with nonzero dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Force_on_a_moment).

Now one can reply by saying that we can imagine the magnetic dipole as the limit of two monopoles stuck together or as a loop of electric current. I agree this works as a trick, but the issue is that a neutrino is not composed of magnetic monopoles and it does not have any electric current, so how could the Lorentz force possibly apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lorentz force law is the characterization of how *point charges* interact with the electromagnetic field. It simply doesn't apply to electric or magnetic dipoles, except insofar as they can be modeled as specific arrangements of point charges.

> the issue is that a neutrino is not composed of magnetic monopoles and it does not have any electric current, so how could the Lorentz force possibly apply?

Classically, the neutrino *doesn't* have a magnetic moment. It is predicted to acquire a small magnetic moment due to weak charged current interactions, but that is a quantum effect.