# Is there a theoretical justification for using $\vec{F}_{\text{loop}} = \nabla(\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B})$ as the force on a particle due to spin?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

We know elementary particles have magnetic dipole moments and thus they react to magnetic fields. However, it turns out that the force on a magnetic dipole depends on the choice of model of the magnetic dipole. There are [at least two different formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Force_on_a_moment) for the classical force on a magnetic dipole:
$$ \vec{F}_{\text{two monopoles}} = (\vec{\mu}\cdot\nabla)\vec{B} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad \vec{F}_{\text{loop}} = \nabla(\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}). $$
In analyses of the Stern-Gerlach experiment, we always choose the so-called "loop model" for the model of electron or atomic spin. For a specific reference, consider the opening chapter in John Townsend's *A Modern Approach to Quantum Mechanics.*

**My question is,** is there a theoretical justification for the use of $\vec{F}_{\text{loop}}$? I understand that "spin" is a property that is supposed to be analogous to orbital angular momentum, and this fact can be used as a heuristic justification for the "loop model." I am perfectly okay with this as valid reasoning. However, this is no more than a heuristic justification, because spin is only analogous to orbital angular momentum.

What I am really wondering is, is there a justification that uses principles of QED or QFT from the ground up? Is there a way to derive the formula for $\vec{F}_{\text{loop}}$ from more basic principles?

**Just to clarify,** the reason I thought this question was worth posting was because another user Chris in [reply to a post of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/704058) said,

> Classically, the neutrino doesn't have a magnetic moment. It is predicted to acquire a small magnetic moment due to weak charged current interactions, but that is a quantum effect.

This answer seems to indicate that there is a way to derive the specific force or interaction on an elementary particle due to spin but it doesn't go into deeper details. If this is too difficult to explain here, then any reference to a paper or textbook would be sufficient.

Comment: It's worth noting that those two formulas are equivalent so long as $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{B} = 0$.  So it's not clear to me why the difference matters;  can you elaborate a bit more on that point?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I suppose the difference only manifests itself in electrodynamics. If that's the case, then my question reduces to, is there a way to predict how a particle with a magnetic dipole moment due to spin would interact with a changing EM field? Maybe the question becomes orders of magnitudes harder to answer.

Comment: The book on QED by Cohen-Tannoudji has a derivation of the nonrelativistic Hamiltonian from the relativistic field theory -- I'm not it's much more satisfying, though...

Comment: @kc9jud This is closer to what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: In your centered equation, do you mean “two dipoles” instead of “two monopoles”?

Comment: @rob Sometimes when people talk about dipoles, they imagine taking two monopoles and then sending them closer and closer together until a dipole results in the limit. That's all this was meant to refer to (sorry for the confusing choice of label).

Answer (score 3):

I am not particularly aware of any answer better than "because the experiments tell us so." I do strongly recommend, however, this [old-and-not-very-known work](http://cds.cern.ch/record/118393) from J. D. Jackson. The hyperfine structure is first described in terms of both models (loop and monopoles) using elementary Quantum Mechanics and Electromagnetism. Later it is shown that all measurements of the intrinsic magnetic dipole of particles available back then were, to a high precision, correctly modeled by the loop description.

As a minor side-note, recall that the notion of "force" is not even meaningful in Quantum Physics (especially in QFT), being replaced by the more general concept of "interactions".

Comment: I see what you're saying and I appreciate the paper by J. D. Jackson. I added a bit to my post quoting someone who seemed to indicate there would be something more to the situation, but maybe not.